# Android "Sticky" interface callbacks

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, callback

This question is more an architectural question more than an actual implementation.

In very basic terms I have network calls made to web services in and android app. When the network call is complete, I send some sort of notification to the activity/fragment so that it knows that it was in-fact complete.

To do this "callback" I have previously used LocalBroadcasts which IMHO was overkill with the annoying registers and deregisters. I then switched to greenrobots EventBus which was great but again I feel like this is too heavy for what I want to achieve. I feel like EventBus is used for multiple subscribers. I just simply want a callback.

So finally I switched to just normal Java interface callbacks which is exactly what I want. Code looks good and its simple.

Now for the issue with these callbacks. If the callback happens when the Activity/Fragment is paused or stopped but not destroyed, then the information of the call being finished is lost.

For example, a user fills in a form then I want to post the data to a web service. I give a callback like OnPostComplete() but then this is called as the users screen goes off. When the user wakens the activity again, there is still a loader because it doesn't know that it has finished since it missed the callback.

I can think of a few solutions to this, I just want to know if there are industry standards on how people solve this. I am obviously searching wrongly because I cannot find anything on these sticky callbacks (Callbacks that wait for the activity to come back).

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have watched that many times before and implemented it many times. It uses broadcasts or content observers. Both of these will not work for me. I use the observers to update content. But this is pattern is not for waiting on a web service to do something like submit a form

Comment: broadcasts?  i didn't hear that word in his talk... but yes,  observer pattern is useful for such case.

Comment: This doesn't help me at all. My problem is not related to a REST content sync issue. I will try to elaborate on my question

Comment: watch it again then, especially 33'15'' - 35'00'' this is your case, and his talk applies to any async long lasting operations, not only to network requests

Comment: Ok i've watched it again. What happens though if you are not storing the data in a database for this particular async task. IE a user logging in you just take the username and password typed in and post that. You dont have a DB that is storing the state of that task

Comment: DB is a metaphor here, it can be sqlite, file, shared preference or just a simple (for example boolean: logged / not logged) variable inside your service